# How to calculates and show values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I created a form for calculating the final Grade from exam results.
The calculation to get the final Mark for the final Grade **Final Mark=((Labs(10) + Assignment(20)+Final Exam(70))/100**

When clicking on the calculate button, the final marks should be calculated and the relevant final grade should be shown on the named txtFinalGr text box.
After the calculation, it should be shown on txtFinalGr.

I tried to more times to get results. but it is not shown. I need help to fix these errors.

The form code as follows.

```
    <form id="gradeForm"> 
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Labs</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtLabs" name="txtLabs"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Assignment</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtAssign" name="txtAssign"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Final Exam</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtFinalEx" name="txtFinalEx"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Final Grade</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtFinalGr" readonly></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="button" id="btnClr" onClick="clrForm()" name="btnClr" value="Clear"></td>
            <td><input type="button" id="bunCal" onClick="getGrade()" name="bunCal" value="Calculate"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

also, The script as follows.

```
    <script>
    function getGrade(){

        var grade = "";  //declare a variable for grade
                

                //read the marks
                var resLabs = document.getElementById('txtLabs').value;
                var resAssign = document.getElementById('txtAssign').value;
                var resFinalEx = document.getElementById('txtFinalEx').value;
                
                var calRes = (($resLabs*10)+($resAssign*20)+($resFinal*70))/100;
                                
                switch(

                        (calRes > 75 && calRes <= 100) ? 1 : 
                        (calRes > 60 && calRes < 74) ? 2 : 
                        (calRes > 50 && calRes < 59) ? 3 :
                        (calRes > 40 && calRes < 49) ? 4 :
                        (calRes > 30 && calRes < 39) ? 5 : 
                        (calRes > 0 && calRes < 29) ? 6 
                      )
                        
                        {
                            case 1 :grade = "A";break;
                            case 2 :grade = "B";break;
                            case 3 :grade = "C";break;
                            case 4 :grade = "D";break;
                            case 5 :grade = "E";break;
                            case 6 :grade = "F";break;
                        }
                        
                    

                document.getElementById('txtFinalGr').value = grade;    
    
    }

    function clrForm() {
        document.getElementById("gradeForm").reset();
    }
</script>
```

Thank you !!

Comment: "it is not working" is not a problem description. You need to provide a [mcve] that allows to reproduce the problem, along with debugging information and a clear problem description.

Comment: The form has 4 text boxes.

Comment: When clicking on the calculate button, the final marks should be calculated and the relevant final grade should be shown on the named txtFinalGr text box. Final grades cutoff marks had added to the script.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your code:

- Variable names don't match, eg. `resLabs` vs `$resLabs`. Names must always be exactly the same; e.g. both *without* a $, or both *with* a $ (the $ has no special meaning, it is just a character that can be part of a variable name).
- You use input box values as if they are numbers, but actually these are strings. Better use `parseFloat()` or `parseInt()`.
- You divide by 100, which only makes sense if the grades go from 1 to 100. If the grades go from 1 to 10 (which is normal where I live), then you would need to divide by 10. I kept using `/ 100` below so the grades need to go from 1...100.
- Your `switch` is very complicated, and it misses a bunch of cases. E.g. when `calRes` is 74 or 75, then there is no condition that will match it. I fixed this below. (And it can even be simplified further, see later on)
- The last ternary operator `? 6` does not have the required `:` and code will not compile as a result.
- The code assumes "happy input": it expects only valid grades (in this case 1...100). What if someone types "ABC" or "12345"...

Here is a version that fixes most issues:

```js
function getGrade() {
  var grade = ""; //declare a variable for grade

  //read the marks
  var resLabs = parseFloat(document.getElementById('txtLabs').value);
  var resAssign = parseFloat(document.getElementById('txtAssign').value);
  var resFinalEx = parseFloat(document.getElementById('txtFinalEx').value);

  var calRes = ((resLabs * 10) + (resAssign * 20) + (resFinalEx * 70)) / 100;
  console.log("calRes: " + calRes);
  switch (
    (calRes > 75 && calRes <= 100) ? 1 :
    (calRes > 60) ? 2 :
    (calRes > 50) ? 3 :
    (calRes > 40) ? 4 :
    (calRes > 30) ? 5 :
    (calRes > 0) ? 6 : 0
  )
  {
    case 1:
      grade = "A";
      break;
    case 2:
      grade = "B";
      break;
    case 3:
      grade = "C";
      break;
    case 4:
      grade = "D";
      break;
    case 5:
      grade = "E";
      break;
    case 6:
      grade = "F";
      break;
    default:
      grade = "???";
      break;
  }
  document.getElementById('txtFinalGr').value = grade;
}
```

```html
<form id="gradeForm">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><label>Labs</label></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="txtLabs" name="txtLabs"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label>Assignment</label></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="txtAssign" name="txtAssign"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label>Final Exam</label></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="txtFinalEx" name="txtFinalEx"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="button" id="btnClr" onClick="clrForm()" name="btnClr" value="Clear"></td>
      <td><input type="button" id="bunCal" onClick="getGrade()" name="bunCal" value="Calculate"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label>Final Grade</label></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="txtFinalGr" readonly></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

And here is version with the `switch` eliminated because it only added complexity + with better checks for invalid values:

```js
function getGrade() {
  var resLabs = parseFloat(document.getElementById('txtLabs').value);
  var resAssign = parseFloat(document.getElementById('txtAssign').value);
  var resFinalEx = parseFloat(document.getElementById('txtFinalEx').value);

  var calRes = ((resLabs * 10) + (resAssign * 20) + (resFinalEx * 70)) / 100;
  console.log("calRes: " + calRes);
  var grade =
    (isNaN(calRes) || calRes < 0 || calRes > 100) ? "???" :
    (calRes > 75) ? "A" :
    (calRes > 60) ? "B" :
    (calRes > 50) ? "C" :
    (calRes > 40) ? "D" :
    (calRes > 30) ? "E" : "F";
  document.getElementById('txtFinalGr').value = grade;
}
```

```html
<form id="gradeForm">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><label>Labs</label></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="txtLabs" name="txtLabs"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label>Assignment</label></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="txtAssign" name="txtAssign"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label>Final Exam</label></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="txtFinalEx" name="txtFinalEx"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="button" id="btnClr" onClick="clrForm()" name="btnClr" value="Clear"></td>
      <td><input type="button" id="bunCal" onClick="getGrade()" name="bunCal" value="Calculate"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label>Final Grade</label></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="txtFinalGr" readonly></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

the `Switch` Statement in JavaScript code is written wrong.

this is the correct syntax:

```
switch(expression) {
  case x:
    // code block
    break;
  case y:
    // code block
    break;
  default:
    // code block
}
```

and if you take a look to the console, you will find a syntax error in `Switch` Statement.

you need to use curly brackets after the `Switch` keyword, so replace normal practices "`()`" with curly ones "`{}`".

Comment: i know that there is other problems not mentioned in my answer. so if anyone know them, you can edit my answer and mention them please